# Cannot use write.csv() as it returns an error "cannot open file': Permission denied"

Tags: r, windows

I have never had such an issue in the past and have previously used write.csv and similar functions on this computer as recently as a month ago. Whenever I try to write any file at all it returns the error "cannot open file': Permission denied." I am running Windows 10 home with the newest version of RStudio and am the administrator of the computer on the administrator account.

I have checked the properties of the folder I am writing to and gave full permissions to read, write, and modify to "everyone" and I am still getting the error. I do not understand how it could possibly have permission denied and need assistance.

Comment: are you writing new files or attempting to overwrite existing ones?

Comment: Writing a new file.

Comment: Do you have a file of the same name open?